# Function Point Estimation

Tags: java, python, function-points

Since we have so many languages to use for programming to create a software product, and every language has its own pros and cons. While thinking on how to choose a language, a friend suggested to loop for the cheapest cost a language creates as judged by the lines of code method used for estimation. I was wondering how many lines of Java code and how many lines of Python code each FP incurs ?

Comment: what do you mean by point estimation? you mean statistical point estimation?

Comment: yes, if there is a statistical point estimation, that would help to calculate the software cost and effort estimation. A resource will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in this pdf. http://namcookanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Function-Points-as-a-Universal-Software-Metric2013.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You should assume a probability model. This might be helpful: https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/13W/cis472/slides/estimation-2pp.pdf

In terms of implementation, you can use scikit-learn and scikit-stats libraries in Python, where you are able to implement most statistical methods in a few lines of code.

Comment: actually, this is the source i was looking, i found my answer for Java but couldnt find for Python in the Function Point Language Table.
http://www.qsm.com/resources/function-point-languages-table